# Change identical fields in a nested structure

Tags: go

I have a nested structure. I would like to change all fields which are called "Text" for example.
In this example "Text" is present in three different levels. How can I elegantly iterate over all (any) nesting depths and change all fields ​​called "Text"?
("Text" - fields are always of type string.)

```
type First struct {
Text string `json:"text"`
Second Second `json:"second"`
}

type Second struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
    Nested Nested `json:"nested"`
}

type Nested struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}
```

Comment: You can do so using the `reflect` package. Examples of that on StackOverflow abound.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I elegantly iterate over all (any) nesting depths and change all fields ​​called "Text"?

If you consider reflection "elegant" than use reflection.

Most people do not consider reflection to be elegant, so the real answer would be "You cannot."